# What is the correlation between X and X+Y?

Tags: self-study, correlation, covariance, random-variable

If $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables, how do I calculate the correlation of $X$ and $X+Y$ in terms of $\rho$, $σ_x^2$ and $σ_y^2$ given that the $\text{Variance}(X)= σ_x^2$ and $\text{Variance}(Y)=σ_y^2$?

Note - This is homework - so far I have this:

$\text{Variance}(X+Y)=σ_x^2+σ_y^2$.

$\text{Covariance}(X,X+Y)=Cov(X,X) + Cov(X,Y) = Variance(X) + 0 = σ_x^2$.

Then by subbing into the formula I have $\rho(X,X+Y)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{σ_x^2σ_y^2}}$

I feel I have gone wrong somewhere however, are my methods correct? Just want to check!

Comment: You should give some context for the question (and you should specifically identify whether this is some form of homework/bookwork).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some general guidance for a simple (if slightly backward) way of progressing:

1) compute the covariance of X and X+Y using basic [properties of covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties) or even just [linearity of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) (and the definition of covariance).

2) compute the correlation using the formula that relates [correlation to covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#For_a_population).

--

Addressing specific things in your updates question:

> $\text{Variance}(X+Y)=σ_x^2+σ_y^2$.

For this to be true you'd need $X$ and $Y$ to be uncorrelated. You have stated that they're correlated (with correlation $\rho$), so this can't be right.

> $\text{Covariance}(X,X+Y)=Cov(X,X) + Cov(X,Y) = Variance(X) + 0 = σ_x^2$.

Again, you'd need $X$ and $Y$ to be uncorrelated for this to work.

> Then by subbing into the formula I have $\rho(X,X+Y)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{σ_x^2σ_y^2}}$

And it's not clear how you got from what you had to this.

Comment: Ok so i have cov(x,x+y) = E(x^2) +E(xy) - E(x)E(x) - E(x)E(y) and that simplifies to sigma^2x + Cov(x,y). How do i change cov(x,y) to be in terms of either p, sigma(x), sigma(y) ? because i know that cov(x,y) = E(xy) -E(x)E(y).

Comment: You have a formula for population correlation in terms of the covariance and some other quantities in my third link above.